# Presenting two paragraphs in HTML side by side

Tags: html, css, paragraph, presentation

Consider the following problem: you have one text translated into two languages,

```
First line // Unua linio
Second line // Dua linio
```

and there's a need to display them side by side using all available space, make them accessible to search engines as separate paragraphs and allowing separate selection. That way if someone does a search for "Unua linio dua linio" they see exactly that paragraph without text from the first creeping in.

I've considered using tables but not sure how it will affect search engine indexing, it's also not very "correct" to split lines in a paragraph into rows. Considered putting one paragraph on the left side and the other on the right and shifting them vertically so it goes like this:

```
First line
         Unua linio
Second line
          Dua linio
```

but cannot devise the proper HTML markup for that.

Edit: another (ideal) example would be

```
Really really long line in a paragraph that 
spans two lines
                 Translation of this really
                                  long line
Second line
                     Translated second line
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that you don't know how to put two blocks of text side by side? See: https://css-tricks.com/left-and-right

Comment: I can put them side by side, but I want those two blocks to overlap and bleed into each other. They would share the same starting position and 100% width but text in one block would be right-aligned and the other left-aligned.

Comment: Ah, I understand. You say 'overlap and bleed'? How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/817smdj2/8 If you don't want them to actually overlap the CSS becomes even simpler.

Comment: Yep, almost like that, only they need to shifted vertically so that their text contents don't overlap. I might have not made myself clear enough, but it would be ideal if I could make one extremely long line that must occupy two visible lines on screen (say, in the left block) push lines in the right block lower. Don't know if it's even possible without breaking up the paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, no overlap is easier, just remove so CSS like this: https://jsfiddle.net/817smdj2/12

Comment: I've edited the question to show an example. No overlap is saner, but it would take two entirely separate blocks of text. Unfortunately it's what I might have to do given that I cannot dictate the length of lines to be less than X characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` and `float: right` in Css like this:

```html
<div style="border:solid; float:left"> This is some text </div>
<div style="border:solid; float:right"> This is some text </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

The last line (`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`) is there to set the positionning of `<div>` like it is in an HTML page by default.

After that, you can play with the div's width and text's alignment like you want.

Comment: In your solution lines don't bleed into each other as the blocks cannot overlap.

Comment: I've seen your edit. Why you don't use a `<div>` or a `<p>` and set text align one time to the left and one time to the right ?

Comment: One problem is to make them both stick to the same origin and the other problem is that a line that is too long (so it wraps on multiple lines on screen) won't affect the other side throwing the whole thing into disarray. Rationally thinking it's probably impossible to have contents of two separate html object affect each other. So I'm probably asking for too much there